# Using apollo server in the latest version of next.js

Tags: next.js, apollo-client, apollo-server, prisma-graphql

Im interested in next.js and also it's integration with graphql.
I found a lot of examples on internet about this topic, the most of them uses apollo client and apollo server.

I know that the latest version of next.js have api routes. Does this replace using apollo server with next.js ?

I found an [example](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/master/typescript/graphql-nextjs/pages/api/index.ts) in prisma repository that only uses apollo client without the server.

I also found another [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/api-routes-graphql/pages/api/graphql.js) in next repository that uses apollo server inside the api routes folder

Im a little confused, because in the first example we already have a graphql server without the need of importing apollo server.

Thank you for you help.